# Find all monic irreducible quadratics in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$

Tags: group-theory, irreducible-polynomials

The general form for any monic quadratic in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ is: $x^2+Ax+C$

We get the following list of possibilities:

$x^2$

$x^2+1$

$x^2+2$

$x^2+x$

$x^2+x+1$

$x^2+x+2$

$x^2+2x$

$x^2+2x+1$

$x^2+2x+2$

A polynomial is said to be irreducible if it's degree is greater than or equal to 1 and if factored s.t. $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ then one of the factors must be a constant polynomial. Also the factors must also be an element in the polynomialring.

Here's what I've done so far:

$x^2+2x$ is reducible since it can be factored of the form $x(x+2)$. Similar argument can be made for $x^2+x$. Then is $x^2$ also reducible? We can argue that $x^2=x*x$ and as such it is reducible, is this correct?

$x^2+x+1=(x+2)(x+2)=x^2+4x+4=x^2+x+1,\hspace{0.2cm} \text{ in } \hspace{0.2cm} \mathbb{Z}_3[x]$

$x^2+2x+1=(x+1)(x+1)=x^2+2x+1$

$x^2+2=(x+1)(x+2)=x^2+3x+2=x^2+2$

The ones I've found to be irreducible are:

$x^2+x+2$

$x^2+2x+2$

$x^2+1$

For the one with only a constant factor we can argue that one of the polynomials is simply the constant polynomial of $h(x)=1$.
For the other two I have simply not been able to find any such factorization, how can I argue for this in a better sense?

A statement my professor said was that if the polynomial has a degree less than or equal to three and there are no linear factors, it is irreducible. Then shouldn't $x^2+2$ and $x^2$ be irreducible?

I'm specifically looking for how I should argue for the irreducible ones, I hope I've atleast made an attempt on this exercise and found the correct answer. But I need help with the argumentative part!

Answer (score 1):

$x^2+2$ is irreducible in for instance $\mathbb Z[x]$, but $\mathbb Z[x]/3\mathbb Z$ is a different domain. As you find in your answers $x^2+2\equiv(x+1)(x+2)\bmod 3$, and that settles reducibility. This factorization means while $x^2+2$ does not equal $0$ for any integer $x$, it can equal some other multiple of $3$ and then it will be $\equiv0\bmod3$.

Comment: I understand. So if I instead would have searched for the monic irreducible polynomials over $Z[x]$, as in the "no modulo" domain then the statement my professor said is true?

Comment: If there are no linear factors of a quadratic or cubic polynomial in a given domain, then the polynomial is irreducible in that domain. Incidentally $x$ or $x+0$ counts as a linear factor, so $x^2$ is always reducible.

Comment: But is $Z_{3}[x]$ not a domain? I'm not sure I follow here. For any domain $Z_{m}[x]$ is there not always linear factors as elements?